# Which topics to use?

Tags: ros, kinect, libopencv, depth

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all!

I am currently deciding which topics from the kinect camera should I use. As I am absolutely new to ROS I thought that maybe someone with more experience could suggest an appropriate way.

In the end I need data, which would contain color and depth information for each pixel of recordered images. I also need to represent this information as a 4D array (or 3D for color + 1D for depth) of raw numbers as I need to process them afterwards.

By now I recorded a bag file with topics:

- /camera/rgb/image_raw
- /camera/depth/image_raw

But then I found [this](http://devel.iri.upc.edu/docs/roswiki/image_proc.html) article and am considering to record a new bag file with topics:

- /camera/rgb/image_color   -- this gives me a color image
- /camera/depth/image_raw   -- this gives me depth in mm

I am thinking of then converting image_color via [this](http://devel.iri.upc.edu/docs/roswiki/cv_bridge%282f%29Tutorials%282f%29UsingCvBridgeToConvertBetweenROSImagesAndOpenCVImages.html) (part 1.5) method to a [cv::Mat](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/core_basic_structures.html#mat) format.

I would be very grateful if anyone would say if I'm thinking in the right direction. Thank you in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32714/which-topics-to-use?/) by [niosus](https://answers.ros.org/users/2034/niosus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 386 on 2012-04-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-04-26**:
You should probably record the corresponding /camera/*/camera_info topics, too. They contain useful calibration information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know what kind of processing you're doing, but you might look into the [pcl library](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pcl).  The kinect also publishes some point cloud topics, some of which I think have the spatial information and the color for each point grouped together.

You can look at them in rviz.  Just add a pointcloud2 and subscribe to one of the topics (say, /camera/rgb/points).  Displaying them as points with Color Transformer RGB8 shows you the color info too.

---

Originally posted by [thebyohazard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1483/thebyohazard/) with karma: 3562 on 2012-04-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [niosus](https://answers.ros.org/users/2034/niosus/) on 2012-04-26**:
Thank you, I already looked at it, but I would prefer to have separately rgb image and depth image as matrices, so that color of the pixel can be taken from one matrix and depth from the other.
But I have to think - maybe I can produce those from the point clouds.

**Comment by [niosus](https://answers.ros.org/users/2034/niosus/) on 2012-04-26**:
Thank you, I already looked at it, but I would prefer to have separately rgb image and depth image as matrices, so that color of the pixel can be taken from one matrix and depth from the other.